# Record Outbound Call using Twilio.js

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I am using twilio.js for making a calling app which record outbound calls also,
But I am not getting which parameter to pass in Twilio.device.connect(para).
I checked its Php code in which its invoked by passing "record": "true"
Someone please help or suggest me something.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't pass any params to `Twilio.Device.connect` that will make it record. Instead, you'll want to use the [`Record` parameter on `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#attributes-record) when you forward the call on.

Alternatively, if you just want to record a message from the caller, you'll want [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: But I am not getting how to use Twiml

Comment: In that case I would take a look at the [calling tutorials on the Twilio site](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-respond-to-incoming-phone-calls). There's a bunch that will teach you how to do more and more complex things.

Comment: when I call through javascript sdk, In my call log it shows two record for one call, why is it so?

Comment: I assume that is a call between two people? If so, then what you are seeing is the log for the inbound leg, between the caller and Twilio, and the log for the outbound leg, between Twilio and the person called.

Comment: can you provide me a code example of outbound calling and hanging up using TWIML and php? It would be appreciable.

Comment: Not sure what you're after there. There are tutorials on [making an outbound call with PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls-php) in the Twilio docs, not sure what you mean by calling and hanging up though. You can [use TwiML to `<Hangup>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/hangup).

Answer (score 0):

For me, I found out the best solution is to get the *Call-SID* from twilio.js like this:

```
Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {
    var currentCallSid = conn.parameters.CallSid;
    console.log(currentCallSid);
});
```

And then handover this SID to the [call-recording API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#create-a-recording-resource) to trigger call recording with a separate API request. This requests returns the *recording-SID* which you can use to retrieve eg. the recording .wav/.mp3 file or manipulate the recording.

Comment: Hi, does this still work? Thanks!

Comment: For me it still works, yep!